# How to declare public NS_Enum property in header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have an `NS_Enum`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Months) {
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May
};
```

...but the enum should be publicly accessible. The syntax is still a bit confusing to me, but I'd like to declare the enum in my header file. Is the following a valid way of declaration?

```
@interface NSObject (NSDateExtension)
@property (nonatomic,strong) typedef enum Months;
@end
```

Comment: As an aside, it's a really bad idea to add a property like this to `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks @Avi, I was just thinking about that. Better to make the `NSDateExtension` a category of `NSDate` instead of `NSObject`, right?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Cocoa already has a rich calendar and date API, and it's likely that you can already do what you're trying to accomplish with the enum in some other way.

Comment: I'm just trying to convert AFDateHelper from Swift to Obj-C for practice. I'm a Swift dev learning obj-c

Comment: If it's for practice, have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
@interface NSObject (NSDateExtension)
@property (nonatomic, assign) Months propertyName;
@end
```

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown type name 'Months'`, even though autocomplete suggests Months as a type

Comment: Make sure your enum is visible in the file you are using the property.